# Issue in previewing a doc file in phpword

Tags: dompdf, phpword

I'm trying to convert a word file into html and then displaying it as pdf preview through phpword but unable to preview file in language like urdu or hindi.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1296.
Maybe u can try setting the font on $xmlWriter->setFont('arial');

Comment: This is my code